# Question on eigenvalues, eigenvectors, and matrix similarity

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-decomposition

Assuming we have the matrices $M$, and $H$.
I substituted both in the equation $N = M^{-1}HM$ to obtain the matrix $N$. I calculated eigenvalues of $H$ and $N$ separately using the equation $Ax= \lambda A$. 
If I found eigenvalues of $N$ and $H$ are pretty close to one another, can I conclude that $M$ is a good estimation for eigenvectors of $H$? (In other words, if $M$ is a different matrix, this similarity in eigenvalues cannot be guaranteed)
Is there any other conclusions I can draw from this scenario? 
Does anyone have additional insights on this scenario?

Thanks

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_similarity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$H$ and $M^{-1} H M$ always have the characteristic polynomial and the same eigenvalues.  In fact, $v$ is an eigenvector for $H$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$  iff $M^{-1} v$ is an eigenvector for $M^{-1} H M$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$.

Of course, in a numerical example roundoff error may cause small differences between the computed eigenvalues for $H$ and the computed eigenvalues for $M^{-1} H M$.

Comment: You mean even if $M^{-1}$ was not obtained using the equation Ax=λx, the eigenvalues would be close to one another? My assumption is, In general, the equality of eigenvalues holds true when we know that columns in $M$ are the eigenvectors.

Comment: you are right. I tried different matrices( M ).So  far when matrix M is non-singular, the eigenvalues of $H$ and $N$ are  the same.

Comment: I wonder is there any relations between eigenvectors of similar matrices?

Comment: You wonder?  Did you read the second sentence of my answer?

Comment: I see.  $\lambda v = Hv $ =>  $\lambda v = H(MM^{-1})v$ =>  $M^{-1} \lambda v = M^{-1} H(MM^{-1})v$ =>  $M^{-1} \lambda v = (M^{-1} HM)M^{-1}v$. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I can give a counter example. If you choose the identity matrix for $M$, then $N=H$ and so per definition their eigenvalues will also be the same.

I am a bit rusty on this part, but if I remember correctly, then choosing any nonsingular matrix for $M$ will have this property (the actual eigenvalues might differ due to numerical rounding).

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly what you meant in the first paragraph of your answer. If the eigenvalues of N and H are the same I think it will not be a counter example.

Comment: @Zereshki You ask if $M$ would be a good estimation for the eigenvectors of $H$ when the eigenvalues of $N$ and $H$ are (almost) the same. But in general the identity matrix will most likely not be the eigenvectors of $H$, even though then the eigenvalues of $N$ and $H$ are always the same.

Comment: I see. Now I understood what you meant. My conclusion likely has a counter example